# Unable to get Windows Phone 8 speech reco working on Emulator, works fine on the phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that uses the SpeechRecognizer class for speech recognition.  The app runs fine on the phone, but on the Emulator I get a System.Exception when I call the RecognizeAsync() method:

```
System.Exception occurred
HResult=-2147199735
Message=The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Source=""
StackTrace:
   at Windows.Phone.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognizer.RecognizeAsync()
   at SpeechRecoControl.SpeechRecoControl.<RecognizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
InnerException:
```

Since it works on the phone I know it's not a Manifest Capabilities issue.  I've heard of people having trouble with cloud based services like the speech reco service due to Internet connection issues.  But I can browser the web just fine on the Emulator using the Internet Explorer app.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you check if [CommandSet language in VCD file matches the one selected in emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206959(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_LocalizingVoiceCommands)?

Comment: @Romasz I don't think I have a VCD file because I am not using a Context Free Grammer.  I am using the default dictation mode.  In other words I'm calling RecognizerAsync() without loading any grammars.

Comment: Then you are right that this isn't probably the problem. Have you enabled Speech Recognition Service in the Emulator (by default it is disabled: Settings -> Speech -> Enable)?